# Finding signal strength for a particular router.

Tags: android, android-wifi, signal-strength

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
       }
    }
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

    List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults(); int signalLevel = 0; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (ScanResult result : wifiScanList) {

      sb.append(result.level)  ;
    } 
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(sb); 
    setContentView(tv);
```

This code gives me all the signal strength from the routers connected . It gives me answers as
for e.g -43 -55 -66 -76 -85 -87. Now I want to access a particular routers signal strength only. Not all the 6 six routers which are connected.

How can I find the strength for a particular router ?

Can you please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the SSID:

```
for (ScanResult result : wifiScanList) {
    if( result.SSID.equals( "TheSSIDIWant" )
        Log.d( "Wifi Scan", "Signal Level for TheSSIDIWant is " + result.level );
}
```